# Does the instruction istore start at index 1 in the main method?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode, javap

Given the instruction `istore_<n>` and its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.istore):

> n must be an index into the local variable array of the current frame (§2.6).

It does not specify what index it starts at. I assume 0. And for a given istore operation it should increment by one.

Given a simple class:

```
public class TestingStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 11;
        int b = 12;

    }

    public static void test() {
        int c = 13;
        int d = 14;
    }
}
```

I would expect the two methods to have different frames. Which then should mean the instruction for storing `a` and `b` would be `istore_0` and `istore_1`. And the same index for storing `c` and `d`. But for some reason, the index in the main method starts at `1`. This *seems* like it is always the case. But I can't find any information on why.

Output from javap:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: bipush        11
         2: istore_1
         3: bipush        12
         5: istore_2
         6: return

  public static void test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=2, args_size=0
         0: bipush        13
         2: istore_0
         3: bipush        14
         5: istore_1
         6: return
```

Is it the case? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *parameters* to a static method are passed in *as* local variables starting at position 0.  Therefore, for `main`, the `args` array is in the local variable at position 0.  Compiling code that does something with `args` should demonstrate that, though I don't have a compiler handy.

(For instance methods, `this` is at position 0, and then the remaining arguments start at position 1.)

See [section 2.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) for details.

Comment: The only thing that I saw when I used args was that `iload_0` was used. But I never see the `istore_0`. 

But if I create an argument for the test method, I see that `c` is pushed via `istore_1`. So it all makes sense now (expect where the first `istore_0` is for the main method argument).

Comment: @gel: There isn't one.  It's automatically loaded in _without_ specific bytecode for it at the start of the method.

Comment: Note that since `args` is not used inside the example `main` method, a compiler *could* use `istore_0`, eliminating the `args` variable and reusing the slot for the new variable, but the common compilers don’t do this.